# Ubuntu 21.04 Gimp: undefined symbol: gegl_buffer_share_storage

Tags: apt, xubuntu, gimp, 21.04

I'm very stumped with this issue. After upgrading to 21.04 from 20.10 gimp has stopped working. I've tried removing, purging, reinstalling it, and everything I try doesn't seem to work. I don't have any packages installed from ppa's that should effect it, afaik.

Here's the packages installed from ppas on my system:

```
apt-cache policy $(dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall$ | awk '{ print $1 }') | perl -e '@a = <>; $a=join("", @a); $a =~ s/\n(\S)/\n\n$1/g;  @packages = split("\n\n", $a); foreach $p (@packages) {print "$1: $2\n" if $p =~ /^(.*?):.*?500 http:\/\/ppa\.launchpad\.net\/(.*?)\s/s}'

oracle-java16-installer: linuxuprising/java/ubuntu
oracle-java16-set-default: linuxuprising/java/ubuntu
ulauncher: agornostal/ulauncher/ubuntu
```

If I go to purge gimp from my system and remove all it's dependencies this is what it reports:

```
sudo apt purge gimp
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gimp-data graphviz libamd2 libann0 libcamd2 libccolamd2 libcdt5 libcgraph6
  libcholmod3 libgegl-0.4-0 libgegl-common libgimp2.0 libgts-0.7-5 libgts-bin
  libgvc6 libgvpr2 liblab-gamut1 libmetis5 libpathplan4 libraw20 libumfpack5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gimp*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 20.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Even following up with a `sudo apt autoremove --purge` and then reinstalling gimp doesn't work. It still comes up with the `gimp: symbol lookup error: gimp: undefined symbol: gegl_buffer_share_storage` error.

Not sure what else to try.

*edit*
Also here is the output of `which gimp; apt-cache policy gimp libgegl-0.4-0; ldd $(which gimp) | grep local` which N0rbert asked for:

```
/usr/bin/gimp
gimp:
  Installed: 2.10.22-3
  Candidate: 2.10.22-3
  Version table:
 *** 2.10.22-3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libgegl-0.4-0:
  Installed: 1:0.4.28-3
  Candidate: 1:0.4.28-3
  Version table:
 *** 1:0.4.28-3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    libgegl-0.4.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgegl-0.4.so.0 (0x00007fe782b20000)
    libgegl-npd-0.4.so => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgegl-npd-0.4.so (0x00007fe782b16000)
    libbabl-0.1.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbabl-0.1.so.0 (0x00007fe7829f5000)
```

Comment: What is the output of `which gimp`; `apt-cache policy gimp libgegl-0.4-0`; `ldd $(which gimp) | grep local` ?

Comment: I edited the original question with the information you requested so that I could keep it formatted nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have locally installed libraries which GIMP uses.

Remove library files by

```
sudo rm -v /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgegl-0.4.so.0
sudo rm -v /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgegl-npd-0.4.so
sudo rm -v /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbabl-0.1.so.0
```

and then restart GIMP.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you very much. Not exactly sure how this happened in the first place, but I'm glad it's working again. Thanks!

Comment: So it seems that these files keep getting recreated and I'm constantly forced to delete them in order to use gimp. Not sure if it keeps getting added on updates or what, but it's annoying.

Comment: I had the same problem, and solved it with the same solution. AFAIK the files have not reappeared. I suspect I created them when I attempted unsuccessfully to build Glimpse from source (as I hate snap/flatpack/appimage etc., but I also find the name of this software package somewhat ableist, but the publishers of Glimpse seem to insist on distributing "for end users"). I finally gave up and reinstalled g*mp, and finally found this answer.